# Reverse skip_files in Google App Engine app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine

I currently have the following `skip_files` in my app.yaml:

```
skip_files:
- ^\..*
- ^.*\.(json|yaml)$
- ^Gruntfile\.js$
- ^bower_components
- ^node_modules
- ^src
- ^tests
- ^tmp
```

This is pretty bloated. Actually I just want to add everything to the `skip_files` except for everything in the `dist` folder.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is working for me :

```
skip_files:
- (?!^dist)
```

Comment: This is much more elegant and it seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: I've assembled the following regex to support subdirectories: `(?!^(spam($|/dist)))`

Answer (score 1):

No. But for perspective, an 8 line skip_files is hardly bloated, at least from what I've seen people do.

Answer (score 1):

Today I tried the solution given by @Alex Kubity and didn't work. I had the error

```
Step #0: node.js checker: No package.json file.
```

So I changed the regex to

```
^(?!dist|package).*$
```

To skip all files except `dist` folder and `package*.json`.

Answer (score 1):

"skip_files" is not handled with python 3, and since "python 2.7 will be end of support on 2024-01-30" (Ref from [App Engine release notes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/release-notes#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20Python%202.7%20will%20reach,their%20end%20of%20support%20date.)) you have to do some changes for migration:

add .gcloudignore file the root of your project, and the "skipe_files alternative" would be:

```
*
!/app.yaml
!/dist/
```